# How to refresh a data table to retrieve new list from database

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have 3 tables, Users, UserGroup and Groups. I wish to implement the following function: When I select a different Group in my Groups datatable, the User datatable refreshes, and updates the list of users.

For e.g. --

```
Groups

 1. Management
 2. HR
 3. Support

User

 1. John
 2. Tom
 3. Mary
```

I select Management from Groups, and I select John from User, and add them to UserGroups The following occurs:

```
Groups

 1. Management
 2. HR
 3. Support

User

 2. Tom
 3. Mary

UserGroups

Management, John
```

I repeat the process to add Tom to Management:

Groups

```
 1. Management
 2. HR
 3. Support

  User

 3. Mary

UserGroups

Management, John
Management, Tom
```

Now, when I select a new group, HR,  the User table refreshes:

Groups

```
 1. Management
 2. HR
 3. Support
```

User

```
 1. John
 2. Tom
 3. Mary

UserGroups

Management, John
Management, Tom
```

Basically, when I select a Group, the User data table will display Users NOT in the Department.

Here is my JSF code:

```
<p:dataTable var="users" value="#{usuariousGruposBean.listOfUsuarios}" selection="#{users}" selectionMode="single">

    <p:column headerText="" style="height:0" rendered ="false">
    <h:outputText value="#{users.id_usuario}"/>
    </p:column> 

    <p:column headerText="Usuarios" style="height:50">
    <h:outputText value="#{users.nome}"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
    <h:commandLink value ="selection" action="#{usuariousGruposBean.selectionOfUserObject}"   >
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{usuariousGruposBean.user}" value="#{users}"/>
    </h:commandLink>
    </p:column>


</p:dataTable>
```

I currently have two methods for retrieving a list of users from my DB:

```
public List<Usuarious> getListOfUsuarios() throws DAOExceptions {
        List<Usuarious> usuariosList = userDAO.list();
        listOfUsuarios = usuariosList;
        return listOfUsuarios;
    }

  public List<Usuarious> getNewListUsers() throws DAOExceptions {
        if(listOfUsuarios ==null) {
        List<Usuarious> userList =userDAO.listAll();
        refreshListUsuarios = userList;
        }
        return refreshListUsuarios;
    }
```

I am trying to refresh my `{usuariousGruposBean.listOfUsuarios}`. I can refresh the list of users in my User datatable only when I manually swap  `listOfUsuarios`, `{usuariousGruposBean.refreshListUsuarios}`.

My questions is..how do I automate this function? I would wish to refresh the list, and have the following output shown in my example. Is it even possible??

I am using primefaces, jsf and java.

Comment: I didn't understood: do you want the users that have been associated with a department to be shown, or not? The way I see it, the users that are already from a department shouldn't be shown there! Please, explain.

Comment: Okay, The users that are in the department are not shown in the User table, but it will be shown when a new Group is selected.I have a many to many relationship with User and Groups with UserGroups as the associative entity between the two. So, when a new Group is selected, a new list of users will be retrieved again. The following happens (Management, Tom), (HR, Tom)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using `dataTables` for these kinds of things is a good practice/easy practice. The way I see it, it's better to implement a `selectOneMenu` component (with lazy loaded lists) for every list (department, employees), and of course some CSS, to look good and 'airy'...

Or even a PickList, it's a better pick...

EDIT:
Ok, then we will have to work with tables: Still, I don't see where the difficult part is...(`are you using JDBC or a DAO framework like Hibernate,JPA?`) for every selected department(row from department html table) you will have to query the database(or a transactional table that contains all the users with their departments - of course the FK keys) and select all the users from that department or users with no department. So, you will have an ajax component with `event="select"`. You will have to do this query for every selected department at least once and then cache the result until a new user is added in a department(then you have to refresh the cached data by doing another queries).

Tell me if my way of thinking is correct...

Comment: I wish I could change, but I can't. It is a requirement that I have to be stuck with : /

Comment: I am using JDBC. Yes, you're right on. But how would u go about doing it? how would the cache work? I apologize, I am new to web development. @spauny